# Span tag with u tag

Tags: html

I am having a problem with a span tag and a underline tag. I dont understand why I can't add a underline tag within a span tag.

> Why would I be able to add i tag but not the u tag?

```
<span>aa bb cc 
<u>
<strong>AND</strong>
</u> 
aa bb cc </span>
```

> The element 'span' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' has invalid child element 'u' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'. List of possible elements expected: 'a, br, span, bdo, map, img, tt, i, b, big, small, em, strong, dfn, code, q, samp, kbd, var, cite, abbr, acronym, sub, sup'

Comment: Any reason you can't add a class and use CSS? `span.somespan strong {text-decoration: underline; }`, I mean if you can't add a `u` to a `span`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because underlining is widely used for hyperlinks on web sites, the general recommendation is not to use underline for text decoration. This, however, shouldn't keep anyone from using underline, but only serve as a recommendation that you use underline with care, so the reader intuitively can see that it is an underline, not a hyperlink.

Underline can be done in two ways:

The tag `<u>` or `style="text-decoration:underline"`.

Style needs to be applied on a tag which is a text section, e.g. `<p>, <div> and <span>.` The way underline is normally used in text,  will usually be a good solution. As far as I have tested the two ways of underlining, they give exacly the same effect, also in combination with other styles.

Officially HTML 5 does not support the u tag, and when validating the code a warning or error message will appear, but the underline appears without any problems.

Comment: The `<u>` tag is supported in HTML5, it's just not known as "underline" anymore in HTML5, it serves a different purpose. [Unarticulated Annotation Element (<u>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u) "element used to be called the "Underline" element in older versions of HTML, and is still sometimes misused in this way. To underline text, you should instead apply a style that includes the CSS text-decoration property set to underline."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. It passes the W3C validation check here: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

[image]